# Angular 5 plunker, Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, observable, plunker

I can't get my Angular 5 [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x2Ufn9?p=info) to work, it has the following error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PersonService

I'm fairly sure it has something to do with the person service as everything else closely follows the application I've based this on.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getPerson() {
        return this._http.get('./DummyAPI.html')
        .map(response => response.text());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create it to demonstrate another problem I'm having.
Can someone please help me fix it?

Comment: Use stackblitz.com for angular, it's much easier and faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.module needs to import the 'HttpModule' and 'FormsModule' from '@angular/http' and '@angular/forms'.  It should look something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PersonService } from './person.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [PersonService]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

See working StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h94pg7

Comment: StackBlitz really helped.Thanks.

Comment: No worries - it's there to help!

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when you have circular dependency of services.